# What are the new and improved features in SharePoint 2016 for developers?

Tags: sharepoint, developer-tools

I just want to ask what improvements Microsoft has done in Sharepoint 2016 for the developer perspective.

Answer (score 0):

There are several new functions in SharePoint 2016 but from a developers perspective  there is nothing published already. There is also no developer preview/tool preview for SharePoint 2016. Only an IT Preview with the OOTB functionality is available.

You get much information about the IT preview at the following links

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/fc34aa/new-features-vs-deprecated-features-in-sharepoint-2016/

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/whats-new-in-sharepoint-2016

https://blogs.office.com/2015/08/24/announcing-availability-of-sharepoint-server-2016-it-preview-and-cloud-hybrid-search/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2015/05/12/what-s-new-in-sharepoint-server-2016-installation-and-deployment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

- Here is the list of features and improvements for Developers
- Custom Web Parts
- Faster Site Creation
- Document Library Access
- Scalability
- Open Document Format (ODF)
- Access Services
- Project Server
- Web Application Open Platform Interface Protocol (WOPI)
- 5,000 List View Threshold
- Durable Links
- New Recycle Bin

For detail information you can visit [this link](https://www.cloudappsportal.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2016-features/#section33).

Hope this helps

-John.